# How to get Data based on ID in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: reactjs, json, firebase-realtime-database, axios, jsonplaceholder

I am trying to fetch data from firebase realtime database based on ID.

```
{
  "users" : [
   
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Short Term Tourist Visa",
    "description": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et",
    "duration": 30,
    "price": 120,
    "imageUrl": "v1.jpg"
  }
]
}
```

Here is Passing id:

```
<Link className='btn' to={`/edit-visa/${props.id}`}>Edit</Link>
```

Receiving id:

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

in JSONPlaceholder i am using id and getting data like this.

```
const result = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
```

in Firebase Realtime Database how to do?

```
const result = await axios.get(`https://tesdb-1516c-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users.json`);
```